# Using routes in Sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to use routes in secha touch 2 application. So it will be very helpful if any body can give simple examples on "how to use routes in sencha touch 2?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`routes` and `control`, both of them define mapping from component **reference** to its **handler**

If you've already known about `control` then routes are very similar but the only difference is its reference part. Unlike `control` (use with `refs`, base on `Ext.ComponentQuery` selector), `routes` uses link pattern instead, for example:

```
routes: {
    'login': 'showLogin',
    'users/:id': 'showUserById'
}
```

The first route will match against http://myapp.com/#login and call the Controller's `showLogin` function. The second route contains a wildcard (':id') and will match all urls like http://myapp.com/#users/123, calling the `showUserById` function with the matched ID as the first argument.