# Routes tutorial : Sencha Touch 2.2.1

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I wanted to learn the concept of Routes in Sencha touch 2.2.1 . Can you help me by providing me any easy and live tutorial or demo. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: as said in provided answer "The very first result is this exact same question from this very site: Using routes in Sencha touch 2" that's why my downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try Google?  The very first result is this exact same question from this very site: [Using routes in Sencha touch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193738/using-routes-in-sencha-touch-2)

The Sencha Touch docs also provide a pretty good guide: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/history_support