# Sencha Touch for Android application - having multiple activities

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I would like to use the built-in back arrow of Android instead of a toolbar with a back button in my application in order to follow the Android design principles.

However, tapping the built-in button exits the app.
I assume this is because of the whole app residing in the same activity.

Can I have different activities in a Sencha Touch/Architect project? If so how?

Comment: On second thought I think this might not be possible.

Comment: If you need the device back button to work then you have to implement routing in your sencha app.

Comment: Got more info on this please?

Comment: I use it in my projects but you can get many links about it in google. One of them is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968360/routes-tutorial-sencha-touch-2-2-1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to do so:

```
    if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // <<< add here your back button logic
        }, false);
    }
```